# How to set $axios token with Nuxt auth module?

Tags: authentication, axios, nuxt.js

Untill recently I used my own register/login implementation in my Nuxt project, where after successful register/login I was able to do `this.$axios.setToken(token, 'Bearer')` and it would set the authorization header globally on axios reguests. Now I had to refactor the app and use Nuxt auth module. But now it seems I can't set this header.

This is my auth configuration:

```
auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: '/auth/local', method: 'post', propertyName: 'jwt' },
          logout: false,
          user: { url: '/users/me', method: 'get', propertyName: false }
        },
      }
    },
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      home: '/home',
      user: '/users/me'
    },
}
```

I thought auth was supposed to add this authorization automatically, since it has `globalToken` set to `true` by default, but it didn't have it. So I tried to specify it explicitly:

```
tokenRequired: true,
tokenType: 'bearer',
globalToken: true,
autoFetchUser: true
```

It didn't help. So in the register/login methods I tried to set the token myself, both on axios and $auth modules:

```
await this.$auth.loginWith('local', {
    data
  }).then(({data}) => {
    this.$apolloHelpers.onLogin(data.jwt)
    this.$axios.setToken(data.jwt, 'Bearer')
    this.$auth.setToken('local', `Bearer ${data.jwt}`)
    ...
```

Also no effect. Though at some point it seems I was able to send only one request successfully, and I saw it did have the Authorization header on the request, but when I switched page and tried to send another request - again it didn't have the header and the request failed with error 403.

So I tried one more thing - in my default layout, in beforeMount() hook, I tried to check if the user is logged in and if he is - set the header:

```
if (this.$auth.loggedIn) {
  this.$axios.setToken(this.$auth.getToken('local'))
}
```

Again one request was sent successfully, but when switched to another page and tried to send another request - 403.

Instead of $axios.setToken() I tried to set Authorization header:

```
this.$axios.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `${this.$auth.getToken('local')}`
```

And again - one request successful, the other - 403

Why is is happening? How can I set that Authorization header to be present on all requests after register/login or if the user refreshes the page and he is already logged in?

Comment: Well, I solved the issue. As I stated, I used my own authentication system before refactoring it to use Nuxt's auth module. Apparently, there was some code from my previous implementation left and it was interfering with the new one. Once removed completely - everything worked as it supposed to.

Comment: did you find a way? Please share.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way can be using `nuxtServerInit`

Once you have fetched the jwt token and saved to either cookies/localstorage, subsequently you can use `$axios.setToken`.for global access.
Below is the sample code to give you an idea.

```
actions: {
      nuxtServerInit({ dispatch, commit, app }, context) {
        const cookies = cparse.parse(context.req.headers.cookie || '')
        if (cookies.hasOwnProperty('x-access-token')) {
          app.$axios.setToken(cookies['x-access-token'], 'Bearer')
        }
      },
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution:

1. Create a new plugin like /plugins/axios.js
2. Register this plugin in nuxt config:

   ```js
   plugins: [
           '~/plugins/axios.js'
   ]
   ```
3. Write your token check and update method

I assume that the token refresh is an **async** method that resides in your store.

```js
    export default function ({ $axios, store}) {
        $axios.onRequest(async (config) => {
            try {
                /// Store action to get or retrieve a token if it has expired
                const token = await store.dispatch('auth/getIdToken')
                 this.$axios.setToken(token, 'Bearer')
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Could not update token:", error)
            }
            return config
        })
    
    }
```

The crucial part is to  `return config` so that Axios can continue with the request.

Credits go to jonasjancarik: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/482